# Is it better to pivot data in SQL or in my application code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a very long & narrow table in a MSSQL Database, one that looks a bit like:

| date | dataItemName | dataItemValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Units Sold | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 | # Customers | 2948 |
| 2021-01-01 | ARP | 19 |
| 2021-01-02 | Units Sold | 146 |
| 2021-01-02 | # Customers | 157 |
| 2021-01-02 | ARP | 32 |

And I'm trying to get a table of the form:

| date | Units Sold | # Customers | ARP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 20 | 2948 | 19 |
| 2021-01-02 | 146 | 157 | 32 |

My question is: are there good reasons to pivot the table in SQL (creating a view or materialized table) vs. pulling the raw data and doing the pivot in my application?

Comment: I think it would be way simpler to Aggregate the data in the DB and than push the result further. Why should it be simpler to read all Data send it to the Server and do the aggregation there? The only reason i could think of for pushing first to the server is if there is any kind of user interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with a key/value table. Fortunately it seems that at least the value is always numeric, so the `dataItemValue` column can be numeric and values like `Units Sold = 'many'` or `# Customers = 'I don''t know'` are thus not possible. But key/value tables are always a nuisance to work with.

### The pros of pivoting in SQL

- Less data to transmit. A row with `date, Units Sold, # Customers, ARP` is just less data than three rows with `date, dataItemName, dataItemValue`.
- If you create a view, you make it look like you are dealing with a normal table. Your queries get more readable and are less prone to errors.

### The pros of pivoting in your app

- If you add a key, say dataItemName = 'highest price' all your queries (and hopefully your app, too) would stay the same, which is what the key/value design is all about after all.

Ideally you use a key/value table, because the keys are irrelevant to your app. Say, you have products, and some have a collar type, some a maximum temparature, some a maximum speed. Your product establishing app would allow your employees to enter the data and your selling app or Webste would display the data. Neither app needs to know what a collar type or a maximum temparature means. In that case you would select the (unknown) raw data and your app would do the pivoting (if needed at all).

In your case, however, the key/value table doesn't seem really appropriate. You want to deal with certain attributes as if they were real columns in a table and your app shall know what `Units Sold` and `# Customers` means. In that case you would ideally use a normal table with these columns. If you are forced to work with a key/value table instead, make the best of it. Pivot in SQL, ideally in a view, so you would be oblivious of the inapproriate table design decision.

Comment: Thank you, your observation that pulling data from the pivoted table reduces the full data volume that gets transmitted is reason enough for me.